# Compare two Excel files, look for matching text and copy value

Tags: excel, vba, search, concatenation, vlookup

I am quite new with VBA and i was hopping any kind of help.

I was working with a code to look for matching texts, but didn't work like I was planning... I want to get the values from Workbook B in the C columns for each match found between two Excel files.

[Workbook A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFQDd.jpg)

[Workbook B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETY2D.jpg)

From Workbook "A", use VLookup to search part of the text inside the Green Cells (exemple: "EGTR-X-XX-001 - Planta do traçado", in this case, the search term is "Planta do traçado") and find the match term in the yellow Cells from workbook "B", found a match text? Concatenate or replace the first/left part of the text inside the Green Cells ("EGTR-X-XX-001" -) from the text inside the Blue Cells in column C from Workbook "B" (for example: "EGTR-O-P29-001"). After that, paste in the Green Cells from Workbook "A".

Edit: Also, In the list inside Workbook A there will be different types of structures (Towers and Poles), and for each one, there will be the design, the load, the foundation design and the memorial, each with its respective code (column C of the Workbook A). In Workbook B, as it is just a list, it statically has the example for a "Structure 1", "Structure Loads 1", "Foundation for support 1 (Design)", "Foundation for support 1 (Calculation Memory)". As you can see, under "EGTR-X-XX-050 - Structure 1" there is a list of notes -for Towers and Poles-, but I would have to replace "EGTR-X-XX-050 - Structure 1" with "EGTR-O-P29-050 - YS1-PR Pole Silhouette", and below, in the list, keep the information if it is Tower or Pole. And right after that, add lines below to add a Structure 2. Which will be equivalent to the following structure in the list in Workbook A, example: Create extra lines to add and concatenate from Workbook A the code of column C "EGTR-O-P29- 051" with structure 2, which in this case is "Pole Loading AP1-PR", obtaining "EGTR-O-P29-051 - AP1-PR Pole Silhouette". And copy and paste just below, the list that is under "EGTR-X-XX-050 - Structure 1 / EGTR-O-P29-050 - YS1-PR Pole Silhouette".

I added a picture of how it looks:
[Workbooks A and B Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfnT3.jpg)

The code I'm using to Vlookup and paste the values from Workbook "A" to column D in Workbook "B"

```
Sub searchpl()
Dim rw As Long, x As Range
Dim extwbk As Workbook, twb As Workbook
Dim myFile As Variant


'Choose file B that i want to open
myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xl*),*.xl*", , "Choose File", "Open", False)

If myFile = False Then

Else

Set twb = ThisWorkbook
Set extwbk = Workbooks.Open(myFile)
Set x = extwbk.Worksheets("B").Range("A1:C175")
End If

With twb.Sheets("A")

    For rw = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(rw, 2) = Application.VLookup(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2, x, 2, False)
    Next rw
        
End With

extwbk.Close savechanges:=False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, maybe something like this ?

Before running the sub:

[image]

Result after running the sub:
[image]

```
Sub test()
Dim extwbk As Workbook, twb As Workbook
Dim x As Range: Dim cell As Range: Dim c As Range
Dim myFile As Variant

myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xl*),*.xl*", , "Choose File", "Open", False)
If myFile = False Then
Else
    Set twb = ThisWorkbook
    Set extwbk = Workbooks.Open(myFile)
    Set x = extwbk.Worksheets("B").Columns(3).SpecialCells(xlConstants)
End If

For Each cell In x
    Set c = twb.Sheets("A").Cells.Find(cell.Offset(0, -1).Value, _
                            lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then _
        c.Value = cell.Value & Right(c.Value, Len(c.Value) - 13)
Next

extwbk.Close savechanges:=False

End Sub
```

The x variable is a range in the opened workbook (sheet B) column 3 which has value.
Then it loop to each cell in x, check where the looped cell.offset(0,-1).value is found in twb.Sheets("A") as c variable.

Then fill the c with value coming from concatenation the looped cell value with the right value minus 13 (there are 13 characters need to be removed from the left) of the c value.

Please note that it assume the "style" of the string will always begin with 13 character from the right which to be removed. `EGTR-X-XX-XXX` ---> 13 characters.

Comment: Thanks for you reply! I used your code but it is giving to me a "Run-time error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument", right in this line -> c.Value = cell.Value & Right(c.Value, Len(c.Value) - 13)

Comment: Edit: Runned again, it works, but only if in Workbook "A" there are no texts in Row 1, be it in Collumn A, B, C... How to fix it?

Comment: But i have to thank you, because it is right in the way i want it, mr. Karma!

Comment: Sir, Karma, i edited the post with more infos of what i'm planning. Any way to do it?

Comment: _but only if in Workbook "A" there are no texts in Row 1, be it in Collumn A, B, C_. When you step run it, in what line it throw an error when there is text in row 1 any column? You wrote : _i edited the post with more infos of what i'm planning. Any way to do it?_. At least to me, your information is not enough. You give expected result example for XX-050, 051, 052 ... but you don't give example for the rest (xx-080, 081, 082, 100, 101, and so on). And who knows, later on maybe you have more and more additional rule. The code in my answer is only for one rule per your original question :).

Comment: under structures, there will be structures for towers or poles, in Workbook B, i need to pass this infos to workbook A